# Show progressbar at the center of the view

Tags: android

I have the following xml and want to display `progressbar` at the center of the view. It is showing at the center, but I cannot able to see other contents which is in the other relative layouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
     </ProgressBar>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
          <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="HI" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <View
      android:layout_width="2dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/separator" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
           <TextView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="HI" />
    </RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: all these RelativeLayout`s are empty? why?

Comment: **what** other content? There's nothing else in this XML

Comment: Just to help others not to spend time for other details, it is irrelavant to the question

Comment: Put progress bar between two other relative layout and set the root linear layout gravity center also you can remove progress bar relative layout which is not needed here

Comment: If you want progress bar on the top of all views and in center u can go with relative layout as main layout

Comment: @Pavan, could you please put into the xml code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HI" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/separator" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HI" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to put progressbar in center for current layout you can do following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">




    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HI" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ProgressBar>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HI" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

in this progressbar take separate space in center between two views
if u want progressbar horizontal center change **LinearLayout** **gravity** as below

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

or u want progress bar on top of all view try @**Jonathan Aste** suggested answer

Comment: Let me explain the difference between our answers: In your example, the progress bar is placed between the other two views, so if you show the progress bar without hide the other views, they will be pushed to the sides to let the progressbar be inflated. But the progress should be on the top of Z axis overlapping the rest of the views.

Comment: @Jonathan Yep I know was not sure about op requirement also mentioned it but explain will be helpful to all :)